# php native Count for the same value

Tags: php, arrays, count, controller

I want to make a program for counting numbers with the same values.

For example, I have a database like this:

```
 INSERT INTO `jawaban` (`registration_number`, `question_id`, `choice`) VALUES
('3311501079', 'P002', '1'),
('3311501079', 'P003', '2'),
('3311501079', 'P004', '3'),
('3311501079', 'P005', '4'),
('3311501070', 'P002', '1'),
('3311501070', 'P003', '2'),
('3311501070', 'P004', '3'),
('3311501070', 'P005', '4'),
('3311501080', 'P002', '1'),
('3311501080', 'P003', '2'),
('3311501080', 'P004', '4'),
('3311501080', 'P005', '3');
```

So,

- I want to count like: On question_id p002 with choice number 1 there
  is 3,
- On question_id p003 with choice number 1 there is 0
- On question_id p003 with choice number 2 there is 3

Do you know how to make program count like that?

Please help me resolve this problem.

Comment: It's better to try it for yourself rather than looking for an answer here. try it yourself and we can help you what is wrong with your code.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note that you are expected to have researched your issue and made attempts to solve it before posting. If you have a specific question, it should include the relevant code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and details of what you have tried so far. Please read [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sql for this purpose. This one if you want to get info for all questions and choices.

```
SELECT `question_id`, `choice`, COUNT(`choice`) AS `count` 
FROM `jawaban` 
GROUP BY `question_id`, `choice`
```

or this one if need count only for a specific question with a specific choice

```
SELECT COUNT(1) AS `count` 
FROM `jawaban` 
WHERE `question_id` = 'P004' AND `choice` = 3
```

Comment: SELECT  COUNT(1) from jawaban where question_id='P002'; how about this?

Comment: @Yosafat Tobing It depends on what you want. WIth your expression you will get only total count for the specific ID regardless of `choice`. With my expression you will get next info: "P004 with choice 3 has 2 records", "P004 with choice 4 has 1 record", etc. Then you can fetch it and put to an array.